# C++ container class type conversion

Tags: c++, containers

Say, i got

```
Set<DerivedClass*> set1;
```

and i got

```
Set<BaseClass*> set2;
```

how do i do this?

```
Set<BaseClass*> set3 = set1.substract(set2); //static cast!
```

Comment: Set<T> & subtract ( const Set<T> & other )

Comment: What is the "Set" class?

Answer (score 1):

Try [set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/)

Comment: +1 - but still has problems with the mismatched iterator types.

Answer (score 1):

Use

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/set/set_difference.html

However you must use the second one and provide your own binary predicate. The default predicate **operator<** will compare the pointers. What you probably want to do is compare
the values and thus need to provide your own predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could create something like [`static_pointer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/pointer_cast.hpp). i.e. you need stand-along template which could perform `static_cast` from one `Set` specialization to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast set2 to the same type as set1, I strongly recommend you don't. You might get away with a reinterpret_cast so long as substract doesn't modify its parameter, but it's a *very* bad idea.

What you really need is a non-member function and, as Dave18 says, you probably want the std::set_difference function - except that you'll have problems with mismatched iterator types.

One solution to that is to develop your own "adaptor" iterator class, which mostly passes calls through to the original iterator, but when dereferenced does the needed cast.

Better than writing your own iterator adaptors is reusing someone elses. I think [boost::iterator_adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html) looks a likely candidate, though I haven't checked properly.